# Using a Cap as V_th in Thevenin Equivalent Circuit With Natural Response

Tags: thevenin

My instructor solved this problem by creating a thevenin equivalent circuit to the right of the capacitor. But what I find odd is how at the end of it, there does not appear to be a thevenin voltage source. Or at least, the capacitor has taken the place of V_thevenin. The cap's initial voltage is of course 4V, but she seems to have used a method that would allow V_th to come out to 0 on the right side..

When I made my own thevenin circuit the usual way, I got the same R_thevenin = 70Ohms. But then I ended up with a V_thevenin = 14V.

Is anyone familiar with my instructor's method? I will of course ask her and update here but I am not currently at the university. 
[image]

Comment: The current source and resistor on the right side are irrelevent. First, that right side 20 Ohm resistor is being driven by a current source. So you can just short out that resistor with a wire. It doesn't matter. But now your current-dependent voltage source doesn't depend upon the current source on the right. So it will simply absorb (or yield) whatever that current source wants but the current source itself also doesn't affect the current-dependent voltage source. So you can dump the current source, too.

Comment: Since all that's left is two series components which each must have the same current in them, \$i_0\$, the "50" factor in your current-dependent voltage source is on the exact same par as the 20 Ohms already there, and so acts exactly like a 50 Ohm resistor, in series. So the total resistance is 70 Ohms. The rest is just an R discharging a C type equation. So easy.

Answer (score 0):

since it is connected for a long time, I think your teacher just assumed the capacitor was fully charged and did the equivalent circuit before and  after t=0(some people call this t0- and t0+) the switch changes positions at t=0 so it is two different circuits, all components to the left are irrelevant after t=0.